An error while trying to add subscriptions to my android app
I was trying to add subscriptions to my android app on GPC but after adding the base plan and clicking "save" I'm getting the following error: An unexpected error has occurred. Please try again. (764F0E24).
Second day trying to add these subscriptions and it still doesn't work...
I tried waiting for some time (~1 day) and thought it's just some google issue that will be resolved soon, but it seems like other people have been having similar issues over a couple of past years

This seems like a bug with the Google Play Console, you should contact their support.
